# Angular 6 - Common input (change) method, how to tell which model value was modified?

Tags: angular, events, input, angular6

I'm looking for a way to modify the input value that will be stored in the model.

For instance, I would like to change the string to upper case when the user types in the input. Or, perhaps, make some kind of substitution of certain characters.

I could assign a unique (change) method to each input, but I would like to have a single "dealWithInput($event)" method for all the inputs.

So the inputs would be something like:

```
<input name="description" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myObject.description" (change)="dealWithInput($event)"/>
<input name="description" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myObject.name" (change)="dealWithInput($event)"/>
…
```

And then in the component.ts:

```
dealWithInput(event) {
    //do some magic to alter the value of myObject.description
    // or myObject.name
    // or …
}
```

How do I know which field to alter? I've tried modifying the input (something like event.target.value = "whatever") but that doesn't change the model.

I guess I could also implement a setter in the model class, but I'm curious about how to do this just with the input events (it might come in handy some day).

Any ideas? Or is there a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: What about [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)? You can subscribe to any element (input) easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could give your input a different name attribute and the name is same as your key of the myObject

```
<input name="description" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myObject.description" (change)="dealWithInput($event)"/>

<input name="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="myObject.name" (change)="dealWithInput($event)"/>
```

then in dealWithInput(), you can use this name to alter value which you changed

```
  public dealWithInput(event) {
    console.log(event.srcElement.name);
    this.myObject[event.srcElement.name] = 'new event';
  }
```

here is the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gg53hm

Hope this helped.

Comment: So easy! this.myObject[event.srcElement.name] <- this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!